# JNA pass stringbyreference

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, pass-by-reference, jna

I am getting this error when I execute C++ code from Java. I placed cout statements in C++ code to identify if C++ part got executed completely and found that C++ code is working fine but when its reaching java side I am getting the below exception.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fd5894aeaea, pid=8998, tid=0x00007fd58a01e700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_101-b13) (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.101-b13 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc.so.6+0x88aea]  strlen+0x2a
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/user1/workspace/ImageProcessor/hs_err_pid8998.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

My Java class is

```
public class ShingleCoOrdJNA extends Structure {

    public static class ByReference extends ShingleCoOrdJNA implements Structure.ByReference {}
    public static class ByValue extends ShingleCoOrdJNA implements Structure.ByValue {}
    public Point.ByValue ShiP1;
    public Point.ByValue ShiP2;
    public Point.ByValue ShiP3;
    public Point.ByValue ShiP4;
    //public Point.ByReference vDamagePts;
    public StringByReference vDamagePts;
    public boolean bIsGood;
    public float fDamagePercentage;

    public ShingleCoOrdJNA()
    {
        this.bIsGood = true;
        this.fDamagePercentage = 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected List getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList(new String[] { "ShiP1","ShiP2","ShiP3","ShiP4","vDamagePts","bIsGood","fDamagePercentage"});
    }
}
```

StringByReference class is

```
public class StringByReference extends ByReference {

    public StringByReference() {
        this(0);
    }

    public StringByReference(int size) {
        super(size < 4 ? 4 : size);
        getPointer().clear(size < 4 ? 4 : size);
    }

    public StringByReference(String str) {
        super(str.length() < 4 ? 4 : str.length() + 1);
        setValue(str);
    }

    private void setValue(String str) {
        getPointer().setString(0, str);
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return getPointer().getString(0);
    }
}
```

From java I am calling like this.

```
ShingleCoOrdJNAList.ByReference shingleCoordList = new ShingleCoOrdJNAList.ByReference();
    shingleCoordList.shingleCoords = new ShingleCoOrdJNA.ByReference();

    IntByReference size = new IntByReference();


    TestImgProcInterface.INSTANCE.callPerformShingleDetection(newMat.getNativeObjAddr(), pointList, 4, shingleCoordList, size, false, true);
    System.out.println(shingleCoordList.size());
```

C++ function

```
extern "C" void callPerformShingleDetection(Mat &FrameMat, struct PointListJNA pointList, int pointSize, struct ShingleCoOrdJNAList &damagePts, int &damagePtsSize, bool bShowResult, bool bDoDamageAnalysis) {
    vector<cv::Point> vPolyList;
    Point pXY;
    for(int i=0;i<pointSize;i++) {
        pXY.x = pointList.points[i].x;
        pXY.y = pointList.points[i].y;
        vPolyList.push_back(pXY);
    }
    vector<ShingleCoOrd> vShingleList;
    PerformShingleDetection(FrameMat, vPolyList, vShingleList, bShowResult, bDoDamageAnalysis);
    std::cout << "Image processing completed" << endl;

    damagePts = {};
    damagePts.size = vShingleList.size();
    damagePts.shingleCoords = (ShingleCoOrdJNA*)malloc(sizeof(ShingleCoOrdJNA) * vShingleList.size());
    std::cout << "ShingleCoordJNA memmory allocated" << endl;
    for(int j=0;j<vShingleList.size();j++) {
        damagePts.shingleCoords[j].ShiP1 = getJNAPoint(vShingleList[j].ShiP1);
        damagePts.shingleCoords[j].ShiP2 = getJNAPoint(vShingleList[j].ShiP2);
        damagePts.shingleCoords[j].ShiP3 = getJNAPoint(vShingleList[j].ShiP3);
        damagePts.shingleCoords[j].ShiP4 = getJNAPoint(vShingleList[j].ShiP4);
        damagePts.shingleCoords[j].bIsGood = vShingleList[j].bIsGood;
        damagePts.shingleCoords[j].fDamagePercentage = vShingleList[j].fDamagePercentage;
        /*damagePts.shingleCoords[j].vDamagePts = (Points*)malloc(sizeof(Points) * vShingleList[j].vDamagePts.size());
        for(int m=0;m<vShingleList[j].vDamagePts.size();m++) {
            damagePts.shingleCoords[j].vDamagePts[m] = getJNAPoint(vShingleList[j].vDamagePts[m]);
        }*/


        std::cout << "Damage String making" << endl;
        damagePts.shingleCoords[j].vDamagePts = (char*)malloc(921600*sizeof(char));
        std::stringstream s;
        for(int m=0;m<vShingleList[j].vDamagePts.size();m++) {
            s << s << vShingleList[j].vDamagePts[m].x << "," << vShingleList[j].vDamagePts[m].y << "#";
        }
        strcpy (damagePts.shingleCoords[j].vDamagePts, s.str().c_str());
        std::cout << "Damage" << damagePts.shingleCoords[j].vDamagePts << endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Size of shingle detected" << vShingleList.size() << endl;
}
```

Comment: what about c class? And package names?

Comment: @HRgiger Updated post with C++ function.

Comment: There are no native Java methods here, or any other apparent connection between your Java code and your C++ code. Please clarify.

Comment: @EJP : Sorry for the confusion corrected it.